# canvas.drawline not drawing

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am using the framework that is described in the (great) book *Beginning Android Games* by Mario Zechner and Robert Green. So far all has been going great, where I can utilize the framework to draw my bitmaps for the main menu. With the framework, I am also able to clear the background, which also works great. However, when it comes to drawing pixels, lines, or shapes in general, I am completely stuck as they are not drawn. The methods execute in a similar fashion to that of the two working methods and my debugging with logging has told me that they do execute, however nothing new appears on the screen.

One source( [canvas.drawLine() not appearing on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058472/canvas-drawline-not-appearing-on-bitmap) ) said to draw onto a bitmap and then draw the bitmap onto the canvas, but I already made sure to do this. My paint is not null either. When drawing a rectangle, I made sure that its height and width were greater than 0. When drawing a line, I tried setting a width to 10 and the fill the STROKE. However, all of this was in vain.

Here is the code for the graphics class

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import com.learnplex.framework.Graphics;
import com.learnplex.framework.Pixmap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AndroidGraphics implements Graphics {
    AssetManager assets;
    Bitmap frameBuffer;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    Rect srcRect = new Rect();
    Rect dstRect = new Rect();

    public AndroidGraphics(AssetManager assets, Bitmap frameBuffer) {
        this.assets = assets;
        this.frameBuffer = frameBuffer;
        this.canvas = new Canvas(frameBuffer);
        this.paint = new Paint();
    }

    public Pixmap newPixmap(String fileName, PixmapFormat format) {
        Config config = null;
        if (format == PixmapFormat.RGB565)
            config = Config.RGB_565;
        else if (format == PixmapFormat.ARGB4444)
            config = Config.ARGB_4444;
        else
            config = Config.ARGB_8888;

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = config;

        InputStream in = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            in = assets.open(fileName);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            if (bitmap == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                        + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                    + fileName + "'");
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.RGB_565)
            format = PixmapFormat.RGB565;
        else if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_4444)
            format = PixmapFormat.ARGB4444;
        else
            format = PixmapFormat.ARGB8888;

        return new AndroidPixmap(bitmap, format);
    }

    public void clear(int color) {
        canvas.drawRGB((color & 0xff0000) >> 16, (color & 0xff00) >> 8,
                (color & 0xff));
    }

    public void drawPixel(int x, int y, int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
    }

    public void drawLine(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2, paint);
    }

    public void drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width - 1, y + width - 1, paint);
    }

    public void drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int sweepAngle, int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        RectF oval = new RectF(x, y, x + width - 1, y + height -1);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, paint); // true is usecenter, idk what it does yet
    }

    public void drawPixmap(Pixmap pixmap, int x, int y, int srcX, int srcY,
                           int srcWidth, int srcHeight) {
        srcRect.left = srcX;
        srcRect.top = srcY;
        srcRect.right = srcX + srcWidth - 1;
        srcRect.bottom = srcY + srcHeight - 1;

        dstRect.left = x;
        dstRect.top = y;
        dstRect.right = x + srcWidth - 1;
        dstRect.bottom = y + srcHeight - 1;

        canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidPixmap) pixmap).bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, null);
    }

    public void drawPixmap(Pixmap pixmap, int x, int y) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidPixmap)pixmap).bitmap, x, y, null);
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return frameBuffer.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return frameBuffer.getHeight();
    }
}
```

As I said, the drawPixmap class works, as well as the clear class

And here is the relevant part of the implementation

```
 public void present(float deltaTime){
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics(); 

        g.clear(0xffffff); //From here down works - clears background and makes white
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.getTitle(), 240, 20 ); // Display title
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.getStart(), 540, 300); // Display start button
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.getScore(), 590, 550); // Display score button / connect with google play
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.getThemeScreen(),740, 550); // Display theme screen
        if(Settings.soundEnabled)                        // Display sound icon
            g.drawPixmap(Assets.getSoundOn(), 440, 550);
        else
            g.drawPixmap(Assets.getSoundOff(), 440, 550);

        g.drawLine(100, 200, 300, 400, 0x000000); //This does not work - draws black line
    }
```

Comment: I am not a game developer so I am not sure but just a random thought. What happens if you use "0xFF000000" including alpha value?

Comment: @Emma, Can I give you a hug, that was it!!!!! You have spared me so many more days of agony, you don't understand how thankful I am! Seriously, thank you!

Comment: I am glad to hear that worked out :)